# Render related objects into Template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a One to Many field into my Template, but i'm not able to render the `Subtask` part into my Template.

Pure overview of my model:

Each TaskID has multiple subtasks that I want to save to my database. And when I query the TaskID I want to list the related Subtasks using a for loop into my template.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Subtask(models.Model):
    SubtaskID = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="Awaiting Query")
    SubtaskNode = models.CharField(max_length=24, default="Awaiting Query")
    SubtaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="Awaiting Query")
    Task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Views:

```
query_intro = Task.objects.filter(TaskID="123")
return render(request, 'faq.html', {"query":query_intro} )
```

Template:

```
  {% for p in query %}
      {{ p.TaskID }}
    {% for id in p.Subtask_set.all %}

        {{ id.SubtaskID }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`TaskID` is succesfully rendered into the template but i'm not able to render any of the `Subtask` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's case sensitive, try:

```
p.subtask_set.all
```

Comment: btw, field names are lower case by convention, i.e. subtask_status not SubtaskStatus